# USART2 setting for stm32l micro controller

Tags: stm32, uart

Is there any default pin setting for stm32l micro controller?. Can we use PD5 or PD6 as txd and rxd instead of PA3 or PA4?

Comment: what part of the documentation did you not understand?

Comment: The initialization and DMA settings seems not working even though I set the alternate function

Comment: We can't provide this info, because we don't know which of all the STM32L models and packages you are using. Perhaps you would like to use the CubeMX tool to assist mapping your peripherals?

Comment: There could be dozens of things that cause it not to work. Pin assignment is probably not the problem. Read and set all the registers for the peripheral. If you know how to set an alternate functions, why do you need to ask if a pin support a function or not? You already know enough to look it up in the manual.

Comment: naturally you wouldnt use dma nor interrupts until after you have the uart working with polling.   And the documentation covers default and alternate pin settings for each pin.

Answer (score 1):

No such thing as a default pin assignment for a peripheral. You set it to the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the STM32CubeIDE (see https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html), there you can see very easily what pins can be assigned to what in the graphical STM32 chip display.

By default it takes default pins, but you can click on the pins to see alternative pin settings for each peripheral.

In the manual of STMCubeMX (older but almost identical tool), on page 310 you can read about how to remap pins: https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00104712-stm32cubemx-for-stm32-configuration-and-initialization-c-code-generation-stmicroelectronics.pdf